# NodeJS : Remove duplicate fields from object

Tags: javascript, json, hypixel-api

Alright so I am making a project using Hypixel's API, it will fetch all of the friends of a specific (predetermined) user and save their UUIDs to a JSON file. Sadly, due to Hypixel having a poorly maintained API there is a glitch that causes the target player's uuid to show up in the JSON file multiple times. Does anybody know how to use node edit-json-file to check for and remove duplicates?

````
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const uuid = "b5cc9c1b-aeb6-4b3d-9ee6-31f608e6e9f0"
const editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");
let file = editJsonFile(`${__dirname}/filename.json`);

const fetched = (`https://api.hypixel.net/friends?uuid=${uuid}&key=f0f0d96b-4789-4702-b3b7-58adf3015a39`);
fetch(fetched)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {

      const friendCount = (Object.keys(json.records).length);
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < friendCount; i++) {
        file.append("names", { uuid: json.records[i].uuidReceiver }); 
      }
      });

      file.save();
file = editJsonFile(`${__dirname}/filename.json`, {
    autosave: true
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how you could do it.

```js
// ditinct the currentNames in the file, if you are sure that there is a duplicated values right now.
var names = file.get("names").reduce((acc, value) => {
  if (!acc.find(x => x.uuid == value.uuid))
    acc.push(value)
  return acc;
}, []);
// Append the fetched uuidReceiver to the currentnames and check for duplicated
var allNames = json.records.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if (!acc.find(x => x.uuid == value.uuidReceiver))
    acc.push({
      uuid: value.uuidReceiver
    });
  return acc;
}, names);
// set names in the file
file.set("names", allNames);
file.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `edit-json-file` has methods for doing what you are asking.
But you can easily add it to your code:

```
.then(json => {
   const uuids = {}
   json.records.map(record => uuids[record.uuidReceiver]=true);
   Object.keys(uuids).forEach(uuid => file.append("names", { uuid: uuid })); 
   file.save()
})
```

The `uuids` object will only have unique entries of `uuidReceiver`.